# How to recover from httpclient java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x

When I use httpclient in my program,an error comes out as below:

> java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

After checking,I find the cause is a wrong request to the website.
Once `java.net.SocketException: Connection reset` comes out,it needs time to recover.
And during the time,any request would still get `java.net.SocketException: Connection reset`.
However,in my program wrong request is inevitable.
I want to know if there is any method to recover the connection immediately so that it does not influence the followed requests.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Once java.net.SocketException: Connection reset comes out,it needs time to recover.

The *website* needs time to recover.

> I want to know if there is any method to recover the connection immediately

The connection has been reset. There is nothing to recover. You will get a new one next time. If you keep getting resets, the website is issuing them. It can't issue a reset twice on the same connection.

Answer (score 0):

Had been seeing this on 4.2.3 due to a known bug, upgrading to 4.3 resolved the issues with java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1280